# Easy way to iterate through multiple std::vectors in C++

Tags: c++, loops, iteration

I have two `std::vector`s of same type, and I need to iterate through both of them using the same routine. Something like this:

```
std::vector<int> values1, values2;
int counter = 0;
for (int val : values1) counter += val;
for (int val : values2) counter += val;
```

Is there any simple way to write the last two lines in a single loop, to avoid code repetition? Something that would look like this:

```
std::vector<int> values1, values2;
int counter = 0;
for (int val : values1, values2) counter += val;
```

Comment: It is supposed to add all values, not the number of elements.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't need to access either vector after iterating over them, you could move them into a `std::initializer_list` and then iterate over that:

```
std::vector<int> values1{1, 2, 3};
std::vector<int> values2{4, 5, 6};

for (const auto& v : {std::move(values1), std::move(values2)}) {
    for (auto value : v) {
        std::cout << value << ' ';
    }
}

// prints "1 2 3 4 5 6 "
```

---

As ShadowRanger pointed out below, moving from the original vectors isn't necessary if we instead iterate over an initializer list of [`std::reference_wrapper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper)s. This can be done by swapping `std::move` with [`std::cref`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref) (or `std::ref` if you need to mutate them):

```
for (const auto& v : {std::cref(values1), std::cref(values2)}) {
    for (auto value : v.get()) {
        std::cout << value << ' ';
    }
}
// prints "1 2 3 4 5 6 ", as before
```

Comment: Could you use `std::ref` or `std::cref` to populate the `initializer_list` with references so you don't have to move-from the original `vector`s?

Comment: @ShadowRanger Why yes we could! I integrated that into my answer

Comment: We need more people like @Brian in the SO community. People who are nice about comment replies/amend them. I applaud you. Also, the cref saved me the moving thanks.

Answer (score 4):

With range-v3 you could write:

```
namespace rs = ranges;
namespace rv = ranges::views;

int counter = rs::accumulate(rv::concat(values1, values2), 0);
```

I suspect there will be library support for this by C++23 (or C++2b). All that is needed is a range adaptor `views::concat`, and the range-ification of the `<numeric>` header.

Answer (score 3):

No, there isn't, sorry. At least not directly in the language.

[Boost can do it](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/utilities/join.html):

```
for (int val : boost::range::join(values1, values2))
   counter += val;
```

Because Boost can do it, you could make something to do it as well, by making an iterator type of your own that casts a "view" over both collections.

But, particularly in the simple case you've shown, it's often not worth it. If your loop body is more complex, I recommend hiving it off into a function that takes `int`. This can just be a lambda declared immediately above the loop. That's what I do.

Comment: Is `ranges::view::join` intended to do this job eventually? Having a hard time figuring out how that one is used (cppreference has it as a red-link from [the Range adaptors section](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges#Range_adaptors)).

Comment: @ShadowRanger Not really, `join` turns a range of ranges into a single range. You might be thinking of `concat` from range-v3. In fact, I'll write that as an answer :)

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
std::vector<int> values_vecs[2];
// ... 
int counter = 0;
for (const auto& values : values_vecs)
    for (int val : values) counter += val;
```

It's not exactly the same as your original code, however it can support easily more than 2 vectors.

In case the vectors are there already as two separate vectors, you can still go with:

```
std::vector<int> values1, values2;
//... 
int counter = 0;
for (auto values_ptr : {&values1, &values2})
    for (int val : *values_ptr) counter += val;
```

Answer (score 0):

I used something like this to iterate through 3 different vectors of different size where one vector was dependent of the two other vectors (first_vector is dependent on the other vectors).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
int main() {
  std::vector<int> first_vector{50, 20, 30, 5000};
  std::vector<int> second_vector{10};
  std::vector<int> third_vector{500, 10};
  for (int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0; i < first_vector.size(); ++i, ++j, ++k) {
    if (j == second_vector.size()) {
      j = 0;
    }
    if (k == third_vector.size()) {
      k = 0;
    }
    std::cout << first_vector[i] << '|' << second_vector[j] << '|'
              << third_vector[k] << '\n';
    std::cin.get();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use lambda to iterate two vectors to avoid code repetition inside for-loop

```
std::vector<int> v1, v2;
int counter = 0;

auto f =  [&counter](std::vector<int>& v) {
    for (int val : v) {
        counter += val;
    }
};

f(v1);
f(v2);
```